# How to perform actions before providing downloadable files in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I want to be able to keep track of file downloads in a Vue project. The goal is to provide a url like `mysite.com/some/path/file-name.txt/tracking-source`, perform an action like send the path to tracking api, then serve the file at `mysite.com/some/path/file-name.txt`

I tried using a redirect but it doesn't seem to provide a file download, it just updates the path in the browser.

Comment: can't you just do the tracking on the backend?

Comment: It's all static file hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a route that captures the "tracking-source" parameter and performs the necessary tracking action, and then serves the file using the sendFile method from the express library.

Here is an example of how to set up a route in a Vue project using the vue-router library:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import path from 'path'
import express from 'express'

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/some/path/:fileName/:trackingSource',
      name: 'download-file',
      component: {
        beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
          const { params } = to
          // Perform tracking action using the trackingSource parameter
          // ...
          // Serve the file
          const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/files', `${params.fileName}.txt`)
          express.sendFile(filePath, (err) => {
            if (err) next(err)
          })
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```

here the route captures the "fileName" nd "trackingSource" parameters from the URL, and uses the beforeRouteEnter navigation guard to perform the tracking action and serve the file.

without express you can do something like this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <a ref="downloadLink" :href="fileUrl" download>Download</a>
    <button @click="downloadFile">Download</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fileUrl: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async downloadFile() {
      const { params } = this.$route
      const fileName = `${params.fileName}.txt`
      const filePath = `/path/to/files/${fileName}`
      const response = await fetch(filePath)
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Failed to fetch file: ${response.status}`)
      }
      const blob = await response.blob()
      this.fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
      this.$refs.downloadLink.click()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Vue3 does come with express, is there a way to do this without requiring express?

Comment: use the fetch API to make a request to the server for the file, and then using the Blob API to create a new Blob object containing the file data, and then creating an object URL to the Blob, and then creating a link element in the HTML and triggering a click on it to simulate a download. i have updated my answer please check it out

Answer (score 0):

Since I also store my files in the public/files directory of the vue project, I opted to not fetch it.

```
{
  path: '/files/:fileName/:source', 
  redirect: to => {
    const fileName = to.params.fileName
    logEvent(analytics, fileName, {source: to.params.source});
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);

    a.href = `/files/${fileName}`;
    a.download = fileName;
    a.click();
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }, 0)
    return {path: '/' }
  }
}
```